# Choosing Eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When choosing an Eigenvalue for a 2x2 matrix, can you choose one of them to be i?
For instance, i have the matrix

[-3i -9; 1 -3i],

after doing (A-Iλ)=0.  Which leaves me with:

X1-(3i)X2=0.

In this case, can I choose X2 to be equal to i, in which case X1=-3? Or do you have to choose either X1 or X2 to strictly be an integer?

I'm not sure if this is allowed since I have not come across this issue anywhere.

I realize this is a noob question but thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about what eigenvalues are. I cannot make sense of what are $X_1$ and $X_2$ for you.

For the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} -3i & -9 \\ 1 & -3i\end{pmatrix}$

Then $\chi_A(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix} -3i-\lambda & -9 \\ 1 & -3i-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=(-3i-\lambda)^2+9=\lambda^2+6i\lambda=\lambda(\lambda+6i)$

You have no "choice" for the eigenvalues, they are the $\lambda$ that annulate the polynomial.

$\chi_A(\lambda)=0\iff \lambda(\lambda+6i)=0\iff\lambda=0 \text{ or } \lambda=-6i$

Now in general if you work in $\mathbb Z[i]$, the roots of the characteristic polynomial in $\mathbb C$ may not be Gauss integers, in this case they are not eigenvalues for $A$.